# Можно ли подставить Class в дженерик

Tags: java, generics

Возможно ли создать, к примеру List с классом Class в скобках.

```
Class clazz = Float.class;
List<clazz> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Нет. Генерики — конструкция времени компиляции.

Comment: То что вы делаете, очень походит на попытку избавиться от параметризации... Если это так, то проще использовать List list = new ArrayList(); А если же вы хотите в любой момент поменять тип коллекции, для этого в яве рекомендуется делать интерфейс, и уже в процессе реализации, вы сможете ограничить ваш интерфейс любым типом, который в дальнейшем сможете сменить при необходимости.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это возможно, но несколько в ином виде:

```
public <T> void foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

// ...

foo(Float.class);
```

Трюк в том, что `clazz` не используется в методе, но позволяет согласовать типы.

Comment: Интересный подход! Я так подозреваю, подобным образом что то из библиотек уже реализовывалось... по крайней мере, напоминает DetachedCriteria у хибера

Comment: Да, это много, где используется.